# When is the ground model $[\kappa]^\lambda$ cofinal in $[\kappa]^\lambda$ in a forcing extension?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Suppose that $\lambda\leq\kappa$ are infinite cardinals. Say that a notion of forcing $\mathbb{P}$ is *$[\kappa]^\lambda$-bounding* if, whenever $G\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ is $V$-generic,
$$V[G]\vDash(\forall X\in[\kappa]^\lambda)(\exists Y\in[\kappa]^\lambda\cap V)X\subseteq Y.$$
Is the condition of being $[\kappa]^\lambda$-bounding classifiable among forcings? I'm happy to assume that we preserve cardinals up to and including $\kappa$, since otherwise the definition has a lot of ambiguity.

We have that this holds (e.g.) whenever $\kappa=\lambda$, whenever $\mathbb{P}$ adds no new subsets to $\kappa$, and whenever $\kappa=\lambda^+$ (since $Y=\sup(X)$ works).

Comment: Presumably also $\lambda$-c.c. forcings will have the property, since it would imply that every set of size $\lambda$ is covered by a ground model one. So you really want something between "not $\lambda$-c.c." and "$\kappa^+$-distributive".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by classifiable?

Comment: @AndreasLietz I mean, in a loose sense, that there is a simple property of the forcing that is equivalent to having this property.